# How to reference Excel cell in powerpivot sql query?

Tags: sql, excel, syntax, cell, powerpivot

I am trying to use an excel cell in a powerpivot query as reference for filtering, and i don't find the right syntax to do so.

I am trying to know what syntax I need to write in order to replace the dates in the query with the dates in excel cells.

Example of a query in powerpivot:

```
select c.Id,
       c.age
from customer as c   '(lets say i imported this table from the database)
where c.age > 45
```

I'm trying to know how to replace value:45 with excel cell for example:

```
select c.Id,
       c.age
from customer as c   
where c.age > [sheet1$a1:a1]     '(this cell has the number 45 in it)
```

and this isn't working.

Comment: Can you use Power Query to help you with that?

Comment: no, because its a different syntax. in power query we need to use '?' and then complete the '?' with the cell we want. here we dont have this option. i need to be specific with the cell i need...

Comment: To be clear, I'm suggesting that you use Power Query to import your data and then add to Power Pivot because I'm not sure you can do this with Power Pivot alone. Check out this link: http://blog.oraylis.de/2013/05/using-dynamic-parameter-values-in-power-query-queries/

Comment: That's a good idea, and a possible solution i used eventually, though i tried still to understand whether there is a possibility to use a dynamic parameter in Power pivot alone with unique syntax i didnt yet manage to find.
i believe there is a syntax to be use as in VBA...